# Por quê está dando erro na variável protect salvando manualmente?

Tags: laravel

estou inserindo um registro manualmente (sem o create) pegando dados do dorm e gravando mas está dando um erro na variável $request e não estou sabendo resolver.

Ela está declarada no mesmo controller conforme abaixo:

```
class OrdemservicoController extends Controller
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    public function gravaOrdem()
    {
        $codigomaior =  DB::table('ordemservicos')->max('codigoos');
        $codigomaior = $codigomaior + 1;

        $Ordemservico = new Ordemservico;
        $Ordemservico->codigos = $codigomaior; 
        $Ordemservico->idequipamento = $request->get('idequipamento'); 
        $Ordemservico->idlocal = $request->get('idlocal'); 
        $Ordemservico->dataplanejamento = $request->get('dataplanejamento'); 
        $Ordemservico->idsolicitacao = $request->get('idsolicitacao'); 
        $Ordemservico->idcolaborador1 = $request->get('idcolaborador1'); 
        $Ordemservico->idcolaborador2 = $request->get('idcolaborador2'); 
        $Ordemservico->idprioridade = $request->get('idprioridade'); 
        $Ordemservico->idimpedimento = $request->get('idimpedimento'); 
        $Ordemservico->idtiposervico = $request->get('idtiposervico'); 
        $Ordemservico->idsolicitante = $request->get('idsolicitante'); 
        $Ordemservico->descricaopadrao = $request->get('descricaopadrao'); 
        $Ordemservico->idperiodicidade = $request->get('idperiodicidade'); 
        $Ordemservico->periodicidade = $request->get('periodicidade'); 
        $Ordemservico->historicoinicial = $request->get('historicoinicial'); 

        $validator = validator(Ordemservico::$rules);
        if ($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/ordemvar')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
        }

        $Ordemservico->save();

        if ($Ordemservico){
            return redirect('/ordemservico');
        }

    }
}
```

Mensagem de erro:

> ErrorException in OrdemServicoController.php line 293: Undefined
>   variable: request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não seria dessa forma o correto?

```
...
public function gravaOrdem(Request $request)
{
...
```

Ou então, quando referenciar `$request`, faz dessa forma `$this->request`. Assim:

```
public function gravaOrdem()
{
    $codigomaior =  DB::table('ordemservicos')->max('codigoos');
    $codigomaior = $codigomaior + 1;

    $Ordemservico = new Ordemservico;
    $Ordemservico->codigos = $codigomaior; 
    $Ordemservico->idequipamento = $this->request->get('idequipamento'); 
    $Ordemservico->idlocal = $this->request->get('idlocal'); 
    $Ordemservico->dataplanejamento = $this->request->get('dataplanejamento'); 
    $Ordemservico->idsolicitacao = $this->request->get('idsolicitacao'); 
    $Ordemservico->idcolaborador1 = $this->request->get('idcolaborador1'); 
    $Ordemservico->idcolaborador2 = $this->request->get('idcolaborador2'); 
    $Ordemservico->idprioridade = $this->request->get('idprioridade'); 
    $Ordemservico->idimpedimento = $this->request->get('idimpedimento'); 
    $Ordemservico->idtiposervico = $this->request->get('idtiposervico'); 
    $Ordemservico->idsolicitante = $this->request->get('idsolicitante'); 
    $Ordemservico->descricaopadrao = $this->request->get('descricaopadrao'); 
    $Ordemservico->idperiodicidade = $this->request->get('idperiodicidade'); 
    $Ordemservico->periodicidade = $this->request->get('periodicidade'); 
    $Ordemservico->historicoinicial = $this->request->get('historicoinicial'); 

    $validator = validator(Ordemservico::$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
    return redirect('/ordemvar')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
    }

    $Ordemservico->save();

    if ($Ordemservico){
        return redirect('/ordemservico');
    }

}
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. Perfeito